# Grouping data using R and plotting

Tags: r, plot, grouping

I have data that shows the activity for various IDs at various times. What I would like to be able to do is to group together the IDs and then list the EVENT_TYPEs chronologically. I would then like to be able to plot when an EVENT occurred in time (time on the y-axis and ID on the x?) The data I have looks like this

```
       ID        DATE_EVENT TIME_EVENT EVENT_TYPE
  1:   520424473 07/08/2014   09:28:16      9,210      
  2:   504344215 07/08/2014   09:10:27      1,000    
  3:   051745297 07/08/2014   09:40:16      1,000    
  4:   961837100 07/08/2014   09:44:13      1,000     
  5:   412980113 07/08/2014   09:40:59      1,000
  6:   051745297 07/08/2014   09:40:23      9,034
  7:   520424473 07/08/2014   09:28:22      1,000
```

I have grouped data before using

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(Allvol)[, list(mean = mean(volume, na.rm = T), sd=sd
                     sd = sd(volume, na.rm = T)), by = ID]
```

in order to work out the mean and s.d, however that dataset was slightly different and I had a column for volumes associated with EVENT_TYPES. I think I need something similar but am not sure how to approach this.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Break down problem into smaller problems, then attack. See `split`, `apply`, `order`...

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have simplified the question somewhat. Do you think it is simple enough yet? :-)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want just to sort the data? Why are you computing the SD and mean? Can you just provide how the desired output will look like?

Comment: I don't want to calculate the mean or SD at all at this stage, I was just using that as an example of something (that you showed me :-)) that can be used to group data. You are quite right though, all I would like to be able to do is to sort the data by ID and then time.

Comment: @David I have followed the instructions on [this site](http://www.statmethods.net/management/sorting.html) but the order of anything didn't change for me. Any ideas as to why this might be?

Comment: Have you tried `setkey(setDT(Allvol), ID, DATE_EVENT, TIME_EVENT);Allvol`? This will order your data by `ID`, `DATE_EVENT` and `TIME_EVENT` chronologically

Comment: Many thanks @David. I managed to sort the data using `sort1.data <- data[order([order(ID, TIME_EVENT), ].` I would now like to be able to plot these on a chart with time on the y-axis and the ID along the x-axis